# Display: none; and video streaming

Tags: css

Is there a way for you to hide a div and not kill the a live stream?
http://www.dotacommentaries.com/index.php/premier-league/
This is an example of my problem.

Comment: When posting questions it is nice to point users to what element you are trying to hide as opposed to pointing to a full html document and expecting users to figure it out on their own. Posting the relevant html code/css is even better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move it off-screen using a negative text-indent or absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide the specific div you like.

```
<div id="myid" class="myclass">example tag</div>
<style type="text/css">
    #myid {display:none;}
    .myclass {display:none;}
</style>
```